# Faced a ModuleNotFoundError when creating new virtual env by conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am trying to create a new virtual environment using

```
conda create --name newenv python=3.7
```

and it failed. Here is the error report:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 83, in do_call
        return getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 41, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'create')
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 116, in install
        if context.use_only_tar_bz2:
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 714, in use_only_tar_bz2
        import conda_package_handling.api
      File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 7, in <module>
        import tqdm as _tqdm
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

and the environmrnt variables:

```
  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
                CONDA_BAT=C:\Users\User\anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\User\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\User\anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\User\anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
                CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7
           CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\User
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=C:\Users\User\anaconda3;C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
                          C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Librar
                          y\bin;C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\User\anaconda3\bin;C:\U
                          sers\User\anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\dls;E:\Git\cmd;C:\Program
                          Files\MATLAB\R2022a\bin;E:\MATLAB2019b\runtime\win64;E:\MATLAB2019b\bi
                          n;E:\MATLAB2019b\polyspace\bin;F:\VTK\debug\bin;F:\VTK\release\bin;C:\
                          Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program
                          Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
                          Corporation\Nsight Compute 2022.2.0\;C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Micro
                          soft\WindowsApps;E:\PyCharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.2\bin;;C:
                          \Users\User\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\User\anaconda3\;E:\Git\bin;E:\G
                          it\mingw64\bin;E:\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core;
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : C:\Users\User\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\User\.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.20.5
         python version : 3.8.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=12.2=0
                          __win=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : C:\Users\User\anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\User\anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\User\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\User\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.24.0 CPython/3.8.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.19041
          administrator : False
             netrc file : C:\Users\User/.netrc
           offline mode : False
```

I have successfully created a virtual env brefore. It's not problem of the module tqdm i'm sure. Maybe I changed a setting that caused the current problem, but I'm not sure which one.

Comment: Similar thread https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9583